# Managing a huge LESS file - how to break it up without a performance hit / duplication?

Tags: less

I have a single LESS file with a bunch of variables defined at the top - here's about 10%:

```
@graybuttonhover: #555;
@font-segoe: "Segoe UI Light", Helvetica, Arial, "Arial Unicode MS", Sans-Serif;
@font-helvetica: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, "Arial Unicode MS", Sans-Serif;
@font-sans: 'Open Sans';
@footerheight: 50px;
```

I'd like to break up my now-2000-line LESS file into several children files, by functional area, all of which "inherit" the variables from wherever they're defined (some single "master" .less file).  How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put variables into separate file and use `@import` in every file that needs them, just as with regular CSS files.

[Documentation for LESS @import](http://lesscss.org/#-importing).